# Do you have to have a abstract method in super class to enable late binding

Tags: java

Say I have a abstract super class. And all my subclass have a public method called `toString()`. But different subclass should have different definition for `toString()` method. I want to use late binding. The question is do I have to have a abstract method in super class called `toString()` to enable late binding in subclass? Or I can just directly write different `toString()` method for each subclass without creating such an abstract method in super class?

Comment: The compiler assumes you're going to override methods (as long as they're not private, final, or static), so no, you don't need that. However, why do you *want* late binding?

Comment: You get late binding automatically. If the compiler doesn't know what type you'll have at runtime (and you say there will be subclasses), then toString() will be late bound. Or maybe I'm not getting the issue (in which case maybe some code and toString() output would help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for "lazy evaluation" and/or "memoization".  Then you might implement toString() in the superclass with an abstract method to calculate the String and require subclasses to implement that method:

```java
public abstract class Superclass {                                              
    private String string = null;                                               

    @Override                                                                   
    public String toString() {                                                  
        if (string == null) {                                                   
            string = calculateString();                                         
        }                                                                       

        return string;                                                          
    }                                                                           

    protected abstract String calculateString();                                
}                                                                               

public class Subclass extends Superclass {                                      
    @Override                                                                   
    protected String calculateString() {                                        
        return "This is the subclass string";                                   
    }                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The late binding happens when the compiler isn't able to resolve the
> call/binding at compile time.

Back to you question, regardless of the example you chose of overriding `toString()`, you can achieve the late binding by creating an abstract class since the called `toString()` method will be discovered at runtime.

***PS:***

I assume that you will declare your variable using your abtract class:

```
AbtractClass child1 = new SubClass1();
AbtractClass child2 = new SubClass2();
```

but if you declare using subclassed, the executed `toString()` will be known at compile time:

```
SubClass1 child1 = new SubClass1();
SubClass2 child2 = new SubClass2();
```